# Letsencrypt certbot -- wrong cert returned

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt

I am trying in install a certificate on an ubuntu 16.04 system running apache.

```
super@fulton:~$ sudo certbot --apache
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: fulton.geek.nz
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel): 
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for fulton.geek.nz
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. fulton.geek.nz (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Incorrect validation certificate for tls-sni-01 challenge. Requested dee657b32542a5344ac78e1c213268c6.7a4ba1bb64bebec8e35cb74fa42693a6.acme.invalid from 114.23.222.208:443. Received 1 certificate(s), first certificate had names "fulton.geek.nz"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: fulton.geek.nz
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Incorrect validation certificate for tls-sni-01 challenge.
   Requested
   dee657b32542a5344ac78e1c213268c6.7a4ba1bb64bebec8e35cb74fa42693a6.acme.invalid
   from 114.23.222.208:443. Received 1 certificate(s), first
   certificate had names "fulton.geek.nz"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

What appears to be happening is that letencrypt challenge is getting the default snakeoil cert back rather that whatever it expects.  I know it is getting the snakeoil cert because I replaced it with one with a different dn and the reported name changed.

Any ideas how to figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know exactly what went wrong with certbot but it was pretty clear that apache was answering the sni challenge rather than certbot, even when I had shutdown apache before running certbot.  It was always running afterwards.   The solution was simple "sudo certbot  certonly --standalone" with apache shut down.  I then installed the cert by hand.

I am guessing that certbot somehow managed to start apache (I know it does a `apache2ctl configtest` maybe that starts apache on my system).  If apache is running then when certbot tries to start something that listens on port 443 it will fail.

If that is what is happening then one would expect the failure to be detected and reported!  Strange.

[Here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/incorrect-validation-certificate-for-challenge/32122/3)  is a link to a good post on other things that cause this message